# Blender not executing python in real time

Tags: python, scripting, blender

Okay, I think I have better way to ask this question.
Say I want to scale up my object by 10 in some axis with some time interval gap between each scaling up, so I think I should use this script...

```
import bpy
import time

obj = bpy.context.active_object

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    obj.scale[0]+=0.1
```

but this is showing the result (scaled object) once the whole script has been executed, what should I do to work it like updating as script goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Got one of the solutions, but this might not be the best one I guess.
Add `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)` after a transformation has been applied.

So updated code will look like:

```
import bpy
import time

obj = bpy.context.active_object

for i in range(10):
    obj.scale[0]+=0.1
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Also officially blender does not consider this a good practice so this might not work later. https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/info_gotcha.html#can-i-redraw-during-the-script

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem when trying to animate a transformation within a script.  As far as I know, `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)` is the only way to make the viewport update before the script has finished executing.  I also noted that this functionality may not be supported in future releases, but there doesn't seem to be a "correct" way to do it. `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` does not work.

The context in which I discovered this issue was a university capstone project that implemented a TCP server in Python (using a separate thread for the server and a Blender modal timer operator to check for incoming messages) to allow an external application to manipulate a 3D model in Blender.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35641460)